# Equation for flat circular/lenticular surface

Tags: functions, surfaces, surface-integrals

We know that $x^2+y^2= r^2$ is equation of circle curve but I want to draw a flat circular **surface**....not curve. i.e. to explain the problem-lets draw a flat circle not move it out of screen (positive z direction) direction say a units. What will be equation for the surface i.e. in the form of $z=f(x,y)$ Though my original work is to draw a lenticular shaped surface but circular surface will also give me idea how to proceed to that step 
Note : we can use unit step functions. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: do you want your surface has corners?

Comment: no if are asking about circular surface..then no.....Yes lenticular shape has two corners ....but circular surface has no corners

Comment: Every smooth surface admite, at least locally, a parameterization à la Monge... but, why don't you give us a glimpse of your progress?

Comment: thanks jamarqz i have already solved the question.....i don't know how can i close the question